# does anyone know why BeautifulSoup Connection-error appears in Kaggle

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup, kaggle

I am doing a sentiment analysis of the replies of a tweet from a specific user

when I write the code on google colab it works, but when I try it on Kaggle it throws me the error. In fact, no matter if I write other code about any other page using BeautifulSoup it gave me the same error

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://twitter.com/jguaido/status/1163970836795207680'
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

replies=soup.find_all(class_="TweetTextSize")
```

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /jguaido/status/1163970836795207680 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))

I expect that BeautifulSoup works on Kaggle.

Comment: This is not related to BeautifulSoup. BeautifulSoup just parses the data after it is downloaded, but in your case download failed, i.e. the line before BeautifulSoup.

Comment: You're not using the Twitter API, so this is not something that we can sensibly help with. Web scraping Twitter is against the Terms of Service and can have your app banned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you activated Internet Access for your kernel?

> Go to Settings -> Internet and select Internet connected. Your Kernels
>   session restarts and the newly started session is enabled to access
>   the Internet.

https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/63544

Comment: That was the reason @chefhouse. Sometimes I feel a little embarrassed that there are answers that are so simple and I cannot find for myself, but I understand that´s the way a newbie like me can learn. thank you